# Redirect from Hash to HashBang using angular

Tags: angularjs, redirect, hashbang

I have published a website using mvc c# with angular and AJAX calls to create some client side pages. One of my links look like this:

```
www.website.com/App#/Index
```

I am trying to setup a hasbang solution to make my site crawlable. I succesfully created the hashbang setup so now a working link will look like this:

```
www.website.com/App#!/Index
```

The issue now is that all my links out on Facebook and so on does not contain the bang (!) and therefore those links are dead.
How do I redirect from the first link without hashbang to the link with hashbang?

My current routing:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false).hashPrefix('!');
    $routeProvider
      .when('/Index', {
          templateUrl: '/Apps/Modules/IndexPublicAngular/Index.html', controller: 'IndexPublicController'
      });
}]);
```

Comment: is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

I hit a similar issue that you had where I need to use hashbang instead of just hash.
I had to come up with a quick and dirty solution for this:

```
$rootScope.$watch(function () {
    return window.location.hash;
}, function (value) {
    if (value.indexOf('#!#') == 0) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        window.location.hash = value.replace('#!#','#!');
      })
    }
});
```

There is probably a better solution out there, but I didn't investigate very deeply since this is only a temporary patch for bookmarked urls etc. Keep in mind since this only fires after angular has already touched the url, '#' is already converted into '#!#' by angular.