# how to disable hash redirect in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an url as below

```
http://www.something.com/sometest/test/#registration
```

some logic is written based on #registration for IE.

Now as I am using angular js and it is redirecting as follows which is breaking the logic.

```
http://www.something.com/sometest/test/#/registration
```

I thought of `html5 mode` but it is creating other issues like links in my page are not working only the url is getting updated(which is expected when we use html5mode I guess). So, I dont want to use html5mode. I just want to stop that `#` thing from redirecting to `/#/`.

please let me know how to disable this redirecting

> Note: I am not using routing and I don't need it. I dont want to use html5mode as well. This is and existing implementation and I need to use it in angular js app to open a popup or something.

Comment: did you also configure the server for html5 mode ?

Comment: I don´t know if this can help you but check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626081/redirect-from-hash-to-hashbang-using-angular

Comment: I fixed the issue myself. It was due the injection of `$location` service to the controller.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I fixed the issue myself. It was due the injection of `$location` service to the controller.

```
//issue
app.controller("testController", ["$scope", "$location", function($scope, $location) {

}]);
```

I removed the `$location` service from the controller and the issue was resolved.

```
//resolved
app.controller("testController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

}]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If your application runs under /sales/ try to set the base path in your index.html and switch on html5Mode:

```
<base href="/sales/index.html" />
```

otherwise,

```
<base href="/" />
```

If you're using IE9, then HTML5mode will work as IE9 is not supporting HTML5 History API

```
function supports_history_api() {
  return !!(window.history && history.pushState);
}
```

see using [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-and-html5-modes)

This will work!

Cheers :)

Comment: html5mode breaking some other stuff as well. I dont want to use it

Comment: which version of angular you're using? I don't see it breaking a lot of application

Comment: I already mentioned in my question I dont want to use html5mode

Comment: I am sure you're doing something wrong, plus your post isn't saying you don't want to use html5mode. it says you have used but didn't work

Comment: Now I have updated the question, if you have something without html5mode then updated your answer

Comment: According to me, you will never remove hash to easily without html5mode. Dude please make sure what you want before the questioning.

Comment: I know I have been on stackoverflow since long time. May be I missed something but i mentioned as much as possible. if i use html5mode links in my page will stop working only url will be updated.I hope you got it.

Comment: seems like you're working on IE9. Update the answer. see if it is helpful to you.

Comment: I saw your update but links on my page needs to redirect to that location. But when I use html5mode true whatever the browser it is link gets disabled(its the expected functionality by angular but I don't need this). clicking on it just updates the url but page remains the same. I have only single page and no routing is required.